# Follow parameter does not seem to work when configuring rule in crawlspider

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to extract the link I want only on the first page, and I set DEPTH_LIMIT to 1 in the crawler, and the parameter rule() in the matching rule follows=False, but I still initiated multiple requests, I I don't know why. I hope someone can answer my doubts.
Thanks in advance.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class OfficialSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'official'
    allowed_domains = ['news.chd.edu.cn','www.chd.edu.cn']
    start_urls = ['http://www.chd.edu.cn']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':0,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT':1,
    }

    rules = (
        # Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('http://news.chd.edu.cn/',)),callback='parse_news',follow=False),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.chd.edu.cn/')),callback='parse_item',follow=False),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("",)),follow=False),
    )

    def parse_news(self,response):
        print(response.url)
        return {}

    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log("item链接：")
        self.log(response.url)
```

output：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wKCF.png)

Comment: I don't understand what result you expected. Did you think `follow=False` will make scrapy ignore your rule?

Comment: I think after giving `follow=False`, the crawler should only access `start_urls`, but look at the log, it still initiates other requests, I don't know why. My English level is a bit poor, I don’t know if it’s clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this is my first question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules):

> `follow` is a boolean which specifies if links should be followed from each response extracted with this rule.

This means that `follow=False` will only stop the crawler from following links found when processing the response created by this rule, it can't affect those found when parsing the result of `start_urls`.

There would be no point to the `follow` argument disabling a rule completely; if you don't want to use a rule, why would you create it at all?

Comment: I seem to know that the role of `follow=False` is to extract the links that match the rules from the response obtained by the `start_urls` access, and then continue to access these links to get the response, and parse out the links that match the rules, `follow=False` prevents further tracking. I don't know if I think so.

If I want to extract the link from the response obtained from the given `start_urls`, but do not extract it further, what should I do best? I hope to get some advice.